# iTunes 9 Podcast 'Subscribe' button greyed out

Tags: itunes

Pretty self explanatory. I'm on the podcast page in my Library, and the Subscribe button is greyed out, and hence I can't add podcasts from a link.

Snow Leopard 10.6.1
iTunes 9

I can subscribe to podcasts from the Store

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That Subscribe button is only active for podcasts already in the podcast playlist that you haven't subscribed to. When you choose a podcast in the podcast playlist that you've already subscribed to, the button changes to "Unsubscribe" and becomes active.

If you unsubscribe from a podcast it changes to "Subscribe" and allows you to subscribe to that podcast again.

When I need to subscribe to a podcast from a link I use:

```
Advanced > Subscribe to Podcast...
```

You can also add a podcast from a link by dragging the podcast's URL into the podcast playlist.

And now I see you mentioned Snow Leopard. I'm on Vista, but it looks like that command is still located in the Advanced menu on OS X.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, it turns out that podcasts were set to disabled in the Parental Control section of Preferences.

Comment: They are not disabled in there. If I do disable them, they disappear completely from my Library.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the "subscribe" and "get episode" buttons were grayed out because I had previously chosen to not show Podcasts in my Library. When I chose to show them in Preferences, the buttons were now active. (Edit > Preferences > [General Tab] Show > check Podcasts).

Windows XP
iTunes 9.0.0.70